# How to pass data with JavaScript to LibGDX?

Tags: javascript, iframe, gwt, libgdx

How to pass data with JavaScript to LibGDX (iframe)?

I've tried doing this with preferences (localStorage), however this does not work, LibGDX seems like it cannot read data from localStorage, it only renames the key.

I'm looking for a way to pass data (Auth token) to the LibGDX app.

Comment: I think a look at [this](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html) would help ;)

Comment: @Kromzem Thanks, sounds good, I will take a look

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like Kromzem wrote, [first hand documentation](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html) is the best location to learn.

For some libGDX-related example code, take a look at the html modules of my [gdx-gamesvcs extension](https://github.com/MrStahlfelge/gdx-gamesvcs/). The [code for retrieving the Google OAuth token](https://github.com/MrStahlfelge/gdx-gamesvcs/blob/8f413f074b7fb39a016544882794fcbf0703b5ca/html-gpgs/src/de/golfgl/gdxgamesvcs/GpgsClient.java#L242) might be the most interesting part for you:

```
private native String getOAuthToken() /*-{
    var user = $wnd.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().currentUser.get();
    return user.getAuthResponse().access_token;
}-*/;
```